# JQuery TypeError - Callback.call is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

In the following `jquery` call on form submit, I'm getting the following error. There are some posts online on the error but for some reason I'm still not clear on what I may be missing in the jquery code below:

**Error**:

```
TypeError: callback.call is not a funtion
```

**Notes**:

1. Although it's a jquery error, I've added the details of the error just to show which jquery version and library I'm using. It's a built-in configuration of jquery when you create an ASP.NET Core MVC project in Visual Studio 2015.
2. The inputs display the money values as `$15,406.15` etc and I am trying to remove the `$` and `,` from the inputs before the form is submitted.

**Error Details**:

```
TypeError: callback.call is not a function at Function.each (http://localhost:50507/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js:365:19) at jQuery.fn.init.each (http://localhost:50507/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js:137:17) at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:50507/ControlleName:203:36) at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (http://localhost:50507/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4737:27) at HTMLFormElement.elemData.handle (http://localhost:50507/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4549:28)
```

**View:**

```
<form id="myform" asp-controller="CustOrders" asp-action="ProductPrices" method="post">
....
<tr>
 <td>Item1:</td>
 <td><input asp-for="item1_price" asp-format="{0:C}" class="inputclass" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>Item2:</td>
     <td><input asp-for="item2_price" asp-format="{0:C}" class="inputclass" /></td>
</tr>
...
<tr>
     <td>Item9:</td>
     <td><input asp-for="item9_price" />></td>
</tr><tr>
     <td>Item1:</td>
     <td><input asp-for="item1_price" asp-format="{0:C}" class="inputclass" /></td>

</table>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">Update Report</button>
</form>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myform").submit(function () {
                $('.inputclass').each($(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[$,]/g, '')));
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: well each should have a function in it....

Comment: Your `$(this)` refers to `$('#myform')`, not to each `$('.inputclass')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of each is wrong. Each should have a function

```
$('.inputclass').each($(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[$,]/g, '')));
```

should be

```
$('.inputclass').each( function(){
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[$,]/g, ''))
});
```